# Programatically get size of core data objects (byte)

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmanagedobject

Is there a way to get programatically the size of a core data objects (in bytes )?

Comment: `[nsDataObj length]` gives the bytes.

Comment: @Anoop: `NSData` and Core Data (`NSManagedObject`) are entirely different things.

Comment: That's why i used `nsDataObj`. You can convert MangedObj to NSData and find. Hope [ManagedObject to Data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2357544/how-to-convert-an-nsarray-of-nsmanagedobjects-to-nsdata) will come handy.

Comment: This should do the trick but what about the difference between the archived object size and the NSManagedObject object size ?

Comment: Sorry not much experience in this.

Comment: Alexandre, please don't use salutations and thanks when asking the question. See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Answer (score 1):

Here, existed SO thread to convert [NSManagedObjectID into NSData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516443/nsmanagedobjectid-into-nsdata)

```
NSURL * url = [[YOUROBJECT objectID] URIRepresentation];
NSData * urlData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:url];
NSLog(@"Data Length :%d",[urlData length]);
```

Comment: I'm sorry I though that this worked but it gives me the size of the reference and not the size of the saved object.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code for calculating both array and sum of individual NSManagedObject

```
- (void) calculateSize {

     NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Event"];

     NSArray *data = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];

     NSLog(@"Size of %@: %zd", NSStringFromClass([data class]), malloc_size((__bridge const void *) data));


     int totalSize = 0;
     for(NSManagedObject *object in data)
     {
        totalSize += malloc_size((__bridge const void *) object);
     }
     NSLog(@"Managed Object Size total:%d", totalSize);
}
```