# NSManagedObject  hierarchy import and export

Tags: iphone, nsarray, nsmanagedobject, nsset, writetofile

I'm on the run to make my NSMangedObjectClass profile im-/exportable.
I try it  [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371749/can-i-encode-a-subclass-of-nsmanagedobject)
Exporting works correctly if I write the Relationships in NSArrays because NSSet doesn't have `writeToFile` implemented.

```
- (void) exportProfile:(Profile *)profile toPath:(NSString *)path{
//Profile
NSMutableDictionary *profileDict = [[self.selectedProfile dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:[[[self.selectedProfile entity] attributesByName] allKeys]] mutableCopy];
NSMutableArray *views = [NSMutableArray array];

//Views
for (View *view in selectedProfile.views) {
    NSMutableDictionary *viewDict = [[view dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:[[[view entity] attributesByName] allKeys]] mutableCopy];
    NSMutableArray *controls = [NSMutableArray array];
         //Much more for-loops
    [viewDict setObject:controls forKey:@"controls"];
    [views addObject:viewDict];
}

[profileDict setObject:views forKey:@"views"];

if([profileDict writeToFile:[path stringByStandardizingPath] atomically:YES]) 
    NSLog(@"Saved");
else
    NSLog(@"Not saved");
[profileDict release];
}
```

But if want to import on the other side

```
- (Profile*) importProfileFromPath:(NSString *)path{
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
Profile *newProfile = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Profile" inManagedObjectContext:context];

NSMutableDictionary *profileDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[path stringByStandardizingPath]];
[newProfile setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:profileDict];
}
```

I get an exception, this doesn't confuse me cause Profile expects a NSSet and no NSArray.
`[__NSCFArray intersectsSet:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e704c0 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',

reason: '-[__NSCFArray intersectsSet:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e704c0'`
So I've got two problems:

- On the one side, I can't write a NSSet to File.
- On the other side is my Profile class expecting an NSSet.

So I tried to create a Category of NSSet which implements writeToFile

```
@implementation NSSet(Persistence)

- (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString*)path atomically:(BOOL)flag{
    NSMutableArray *temp = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:self.count];
    for(id element in self)
        [temp addObject:element];
    return [temp writeToFile:path atomically:flag];
}

+ (id)setWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)aPath{
    return [NSSet setWithArray:[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:aPath]];
}
@end
```

But my functions aren't called.

Is there a other way to write my NSSet or tell `setValuesForKeysWithDictionary` the Key "views" is a NSArray?

Or a easy Way to im-/export ManagedObjects?

Comment: `NSSet` has an instance method `- (NSArray *)allObjects` and a class method `+ (id)setWithArray:(NSArray *)array` which may help you.

Comment: `[__NSCFArray intersectsSet:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e704c0  

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray intersectsSet:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e704c0'`  
like i said Profile expects a NSSet and calls functions of NSSet and not the NSArray methods

Comment: +1: might want to add the exception in to your question so its easier to spot. otherwise, gl on the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got problems with the nested NSDictonarys, so i said goodbye to the dynamic way.
Here is my complete Solution to help others
**ViewController to call the im/export functions**

```
- (void) exportProfile:(Profile *)profile toPath:(NSString *)path{
    //Call the NSManagedobject function to export
    NSDictionary *profileDict = [self.selectedProfile dictionaryForExport];

    if([profileDict writeToFile:[path stringByStandardizingPath] atomically:YES]) 
        NSLog(@"Saved");
    else
        NSLog(@"Not saved");
}

- (void) importProfileFromPath:(NSString *)path{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
    Profile *newProfile = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Profile" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    //load dictonary from file
    NSMutableDictionary *profileDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[path stringByStandardizingPath]];
    //call the NSManagedObjects import function
    [newProfile importWithDictonary:profileDict context:context];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error]) {

        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
}
```

**NSManagedObject functions** i got a hierarchy so i put them in each of my NSManagedObjects

```
- (void) importWithDictonary:(NSDictionary*)dict context:(NSManagedObjectContext*)context{
    self.name = [dict objectForKey:@"name"];

    //Relationship
    for (NSDictionary *view in [dict objectForKey:@"views"]) {
        View *tempView = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"View" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        [tempView importWithDictonary:view context:context];
        tempView.profile = self;
        [self addViewsObject:tempView];
    }
}

- (NSDictionary*) dictionaryForExport{ 
    //propertys
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[[self dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:[[[self entity] attributesByName] allKeys]] mutableCopy] autorelease];
    NSURL *objectID = [[self objectID] URIRepresentation];
    [dict setObject: [objectID absoluteString] forKey:@"objectID"];
    NSMutableArray *views = [NSMutableArray array];

    //relationship
    for (View *view in self.views) {
        [views addObject:[view dictionaryForExport]];
    }
    [dict setObject:views forKey:@"views"];
    return dict;
}
```

not the most beautiful solution but it works :)
and i have still to figure out how to avoid duplicates in my n:m relationship

Thanks

Comment: Any particular use of this statement while exporting the dictionary? -  NSURL *objectID = [[self objectID] URIRepresentation];

Answer (score 1):

You could try overriding NSManagedObject's default implementation of setValuesForKeysWithDictionary ?

Looking at [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) you should only have to implement [setValue:forKey:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) in your subclasses?

You should be able grab the NSSet in there and deal with it yourself before the exception gets thrown?

[Disclaimer - I have never done this!]

Comment: thanks, thought about this on my way home, will try it tomorrow.