# Adding a subclass of NSManagedObject Item to the UIPasteboard - Cut, Copy, Paste

Tags: nsmanagedobject, nskeyedarchiver, nscoding, uipasteboard

I'm trying to implement Cut, Copy, Paste in my Application. The Items that I would like to store on the UIPasteboard are a subclasses of NSManagedObject.

I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371749/can-i-encode-a-subclass-of-nsmanagedobject/1375120#1375120) and it was great up until I need to copy the relationships. I started with `self.entity.attributesByName.allKeys`

```
for (NSString *theKey in self.entity.attributesByName.allKeys) {
    id theValue = [self valueForKey:theKey];
    if (theValue) {
        [screenCDElementDict setObject:theValue forKey:theKey];
    }
}
```

Then Added `self.entity.relationshipsByName.allKeys`

```
for (NSString *theKey in self.entity.relationshipsByName.allKeys) {
    id theValue = [self valueForKey:theKey];
    if (theValue) {
        [screenCDElementDict setObject:theValue forKey:theKey];
    }
```

Then ended up just using `self.entity.propertiesByName.allKeys`

```
for (NSString *theKey in self.entity.propertiesByName.allKeys) {
    id theValue = [self valueForKey:theKey];
    if (theValue) {
        [screenCDElementDict setObject:theValue forKey:theKey];
    }
}
```

When I archive `screenCDElementDict` with the statement
`[archiver encodeObject:screenCDElementDict forKey: @"TheObject"];`

I get an error saying:

`-[MyNSManagesObjectRelation encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x72db3d0`

So it looks like it is trying to make a copy of the relarionship entity, not the relationship pointer to the entity.

I don't want to copy the actual relationship entity itself, just the pointer to it.
So when I paste the new Item, I create a new NSManagesObject and can then relate to the referenced entities from the original NSManagedObject to the new NSManagedObject.

Seems like the whole reason for copying out all of the attributes and relations manually was because encodeWithCoder and managed Objects do not play nicely.

Even the answer that mentions having to call `[super initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:]` does not mention anything about copying a pointer to the relationships for the entity.

I could create my archive for each relationship entity NSManagedObject too, though when I create the new Master, I would not be referring the existing relationship entity, but would be creating a new one...

Thanks,
  Scott<-